# Cannot be selected and deleted items do not return to the list in typeahead react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

We put `this.state.todos` in`option`. `this.state.todos.slice (0.2)` I put in `selected`. However, I cannot select items and the deleted item does not go back to the list. I'm using the typeahead react bootstrap library

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-agfvwn?file=index.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: [{
        id:1,
        name: 'paul'
      },
      {
        id:2,
        name: 'gregor'
      },
      {
        id:3,
        name: 'martin'
      }],
    };
  }

  handleSelect = (statusFilter) => {
    console.log(statusFilter)

    this.setState({
      todos: statusFilter
    })   
  }



  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Typeahead
          multiple
          id={'sasas'}
          selected={this.state.todos.slice(0,2)}
          labelKey="name"
          onChange={this.handleSelect}
          options={this.state.todos}
          ref={(ref) => this._typeahead = ref}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this what you looking for : you need another array to store your option which you can use to retrieve your options:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import {Typeahead} from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';


class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos:[
        {
        id:1,
        name: 'paul'
      },
      {
        id:2,
        name: 'gregor'
      },
      ],
      list: [{
        id:1,
        name: 'paul'
      },
      {
        id:2,
        name: 'gregor'
      },
      {
        id:3,
        name: 'martin'
      }],
    };
  }

  handleSelect = (statusFilter) => {
    console.log(statusFilter)

    this.setState({
      todos: statusFilter
    })   
  }



  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Typeahead
          multiple
          id={'sasas'}
          selected={this.state.todos}
          labelKey="name"
          onChange={this.handleSelect}
          options={this.state.list}
          ref={(ref) => this._typeahead = ref}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```